# Delete all files without user permissions

Tags: permissions, find, rm, ownership

I have a prompt that asks me to delete all the files in a directory that the owner (u) can't `r`, `w`, nor `x`, in one command.

I tried this command:

```
find data -type f ! -perm -u=rwx -exec rm -f {} \;
```

... but I think it removes too many files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* you want this, which assumes that you are using GNU `find` specifically:

```
find -type f \! -perm /u=rwx -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

Note that I added an `echo` for testing.

If the files that get printed match your expectations, take it out. :)

Comment: Simpler to use `-delete` than spawning another process just to run `rm`, surely?

Comment: True that ... I just didn't feel like making too many modifications to the original.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a Linux system, you likely have GNU `find` and can follow the example in the other answer, using `find data -type f ! -perm /u=rwx -delete`.

If you're not on a Linux system, you're likely on a BSD system (like macOS, or one of the open-source BSDs), with a `find` that does not understand the non-standard `/u` syntax for the argument to the `-perm` predicate.  In this case, you can use `stat` on each file to single out the symbolic user permissions and test them against the string `---` (which means the user doesn't have any permissions to the file):

```bash
find data -type f -exec sh -c '[ "$(stat -f %SHp "$1")" = --- ]' sh {} \; -print
```

This assumes BSD `stat`, not Linux `stat`.  The `-f %SHp` option will format the `stat` output as the "high" (`H`, the user bits) symbolic (`S`) permission bits (`p`) for the given file.  The equivalent with the common Linux `stat` would be to use `-c %f` and then match that against the `?0??` shell pattern.

You would change `-print` to `-delete` to actually delete files.

A slightly more efficient variant that does not start a new shell for each and every file:

```bash
find data -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        [ "$(stat -f %SHp "$pathname")" = --- ] && echo rm "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

Remove the `echo` to remove files.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of *rawhide* (*rh*) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide)

With *rawhide* (*rh*) you can do:

```
rh -UUU data 'f && !ur && !uw && !ux'
```

`-UUU` unlinks/deletes/removes the matches.

`data` is a path to search.

The rest is the search criteria:

`f` means it's a regular file.

`!ur` means the owner-readable permission bit isn't set.

`!uw` means the owner-writable permission bit isn't set.

`!ux` means the owner-executable permission bit isn't set.

The last three could be done a little more concisely with `none(0700)` instead:

```
rh -UUU data 'f && none(0700)'
```

Of course, it will only be able to delete the matches if the user has write permission to the directories containing the matching files. If that's a problem, you might need to incorporate sudo:

```
    rh -x 'sudo rm %s' data 'f && !ur && !uw && !ux'
```

`-x ...` executes the given shell command on each match.

`%s` is replaced with the matching filepath (like find's `{}`).

**BUT** Note that this doesn't work if there are access control lists.

If there are ACLs and the owner of all of the files being checked is the current user, then you can use the `access(2)` system call to check access properly.

`GNU find` has `-readable`, `-writable`, and `-executable` which performs real access checks, and `rh` has `ir`, `iw`, and `ix` for this.

```
rh -UUU data 'f && !ir && !iw && !ix'
```

But that only helps if the current user is the owner of all of the files in question. If the files can have ACLs and different owners, then the `access(2)` method won't help. So hopefully you don't have that situation.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
rm -- data/**/*(D.^rwx)
```